# ("Websocket" in window) doesn't appear to work?

Tags: javascript, websocket

I was told this was supposed to work in Chrome, but the check always results as `false`.

Here is my code:

```js
if("Websocket" in window){
    Echo.socket = new WebSocket(host);
} else if("MozWebsocket" in window) {
    Echo.socket = new MozWebSocket(host);
} else {
    console.log("Error: websocket is not supported by this browser");
    return;
}
```

I always get the `Error: websocket...` in the console. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your capitalization of the words `"Websocket"` and `"MozWebsocket"` is wrong. You need a capital letter `S` for socket.

You need to check for `"WebSocket"` and `"MozWebSocket"` in `window`.

Comment: Thank you! I make these mistakes too often.